# SPRING REST: The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, file-upload

I did a POC for spring 3 rest multipart file upload. Its working fine. But when i tried integrating with my application i am facing issues.

It throws following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request;
nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException:
the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found**"
```

Please let me know if I am wrong in any part of my code.

Beans:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
 <property name="order" value="1" />
 <property name="mediaTypes">
 <map>
   <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
   <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
   <entry key="file" value="multipart/mixed" />
 </map>
</property>
</bean>
<!-- multipart resolver -->
 <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000" />
 </bean>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MultipleFilesRecieve {
    @RequestMapping ( value = "/saveMultiple", method = RequestMethod.POST )
        public String save( FileUploadForm uploadForm ) {
        List<MultipartFile> files = uploadForm.getFiles( );
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>( );
        if ( null != files && files.size( ) > 0 ) {
            for ( MultipartFile multipartFile : files ) {
                String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename( );
                fileNames.add( fileName );
            }
        }
        return "multifileSuccess";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

The problem isn't in your code - it's in your request. You're missing boundary in your multipart request. As it said in [specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html):

> The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter,
>   "boundary", which is used to specify the encapsulation boundary. The
>   encapsulation boundary is defined as a line consisting entirely of two
>   hyphen characters ("-", decimal code 45) followed by the boundary
>   parameter value from the Content-Type header field.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081079/rest-http-post-multipart-with-json) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344455/unable-to-send-a-multipart-mixed-request-to-spring-mvc-based-rest-service) posts should also be helpful.

Comment: hey @sermolaev, can you give one example of boundary value?

Answer (score 6):

@sermolaev is right in his answer.

I want to share my experience related to this problem. I've encountered this problem in Postman, but I could not understand the root cause for it for a long time. My request template seemed to be correct cause Postman included `boundary` in it...

Eventually I've discovered that when you're specifying `Content-Type=multipart/form` header by yourself, it overrides the one added automatically by Postman. And this leads to the same error as yours. My solution was as simple as removing `Content-Type` header.

Comment: I wasted 1 day of searching in the web to realize that the answer is as simple as removing `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` from the Header in the Retrofit request.

Comment: I lost a day and part of a weekend worrying about this. Postman could warn us about that - if we set the content-type ourselves it causes issues! Or it could be more obvious about generating the content-type when posting form data. Both!

Answer (score 1):

Don't supply `Content-Type` header in the request. It will work.

Comment: Bhai sahi bola tha

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any security filters?
My problem was solved by removing the Security Filter Chain. 
From this:

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build();
```

to this:

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
```

I opened an issue where I explain the details:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12114