# Unexpecteble behavior of multipart request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I have method for multipart request

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Photo> updatePhoto(@RequestHeader(value="Access-key") String accessKey,
                                     @RequestHeader(value="Secret-key") String secretKey,
                                     @PathVariable("file") MultipartFile file)
```

When I test it in postman without content-type:multipart/form-data header it works when with it I get

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Why it happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SPRING REST: The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462642/spring-rest-the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found)