# Express js post multipart form data to external API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, post, requestjs

I have an angular application and express server a middle ware which call the external API

```
    $scope.uploadLayout = function(){
    $scope.selectedTemplate.selected = $scope.items;
    var fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('name', $scope.template.name)
    fd.append('description', $scope.template.desc)
    fd.append('file', $scope.template.file)
    $http.post('/layout/template',fd,{
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).then(function(response){
        getLayoutRules()
        console.log("file uploaded successfully")
    })//add error callback
    console.log('test')
}
```

The main problem occurs when express sends the data to the external API

```
  app.post('/layout/template', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body.name);
  var formdata = new Buffer(req.files)
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('name', req.body.name)
  form.append('description', req.body.description)
  form.append('file', formdata)
  console.log(form)
  var contentLength = req.files.length;
  var url = `${apiUrl}/layout/template`
  // var r = request.post(url,{
  //     headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined}
  // }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  //     if (err) {
  //         return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  //       }
  //       console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  // })
  request({
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    url:url,
    method:'POST',
    body: form
  },function(err,body,res){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(body)
  })

});
```

I have checked the form is generating properly but the external API server gives me an error saying that

> "The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

Kindly help, or is there any other way round it

UPDATE

I modified the code a bit to send the request headers fetched from the browser

```
app.post('/layout/template', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  var header = req.headers['content-type']
  var formdata = new Buffer(req.files)
  console.log(formdata)
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('name', req.body.name)
  fd.append('description', req.body.description)
  fd.append('file', formdata)
  //var contentLength = req.files.length;
  //console.log(contentLength)
  var url = `${apiUrl}/layout/template`
  //console.log(fd)
  // var r = request.post(url,{
  //     headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined}
  // }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  //     if (err) {
  //         return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  //       }
  //       console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  // })
  request({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': header
    },
    url:url,
    method:'POST',
    body: fd
  },function(err,body,res){
    //console.log(body)
    console.log(res)
  })
  //console.log(request)

});
```

So now i am sending the same boundary set by browser but now the form parameters are not detected by java server

Comment: Same error, different stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462642/spring-rest-the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found

Comment: Instead of `body: fd`, use `formData: fd`. See [form-data  -  Integration with other libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data#integration-with-other-libraries) and [request - multipart/form-data (Multipart Form Uploads)](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads).

Comment: tried that as well , no luck