# Exception : Stream is closed during downloading multiple attachments

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have requirement where a user can upload a file and later if other user see that he can download a file. New requirement suggest that now a user can upload multiple attachments and any user who see it can download multiple attachment as well.

So i took a list in which attachments are added and direct it to download controller, i changed the earlier line and kept a for-loop but during download only first attachment is downloaded and later it gives exception stream is closed.Below is the code of controller.Please let me know how can i over come this?

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Download content")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/content/{id}/download/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> downloadContent(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id") final Long id)
        throws IOException, APIException {
    Content content = null;
    try {
        content = this.contentService.get(this.contentUtils.getContentObject(id));
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        throw new APIException("Access denied");
    }
    if (null == content) {
        throw new APIException("Invalid content id");
    }
    List<Document> documentList = this.contentService.getDocumentByContent(content);
    if (documentList != null && !documentList.isEmpty()) {
        //Document document = documentList.get(0); //If multiple files supported?, then need to be handled here
        for (Document document : documentList) {
            File file = new File(document.getLocalFilePath());
            if (file.exists()) {
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
                try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();) {
                    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, sos);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("File not found during content download" + id, e);
                    throw new APIException("Error during content download:" + id);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    s3FileUtil.download(document.getS3Url(), document.getLocalFilePath());
                } catch (S3UtilException e) {
                    throw new APIException("Document not found");
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        //404
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

practically you cannot download all the files at once. Because, once you open a stream and write the file content to the stream, you have to close the stream. 

When you add the files in `for` loop, you have to append the file content instead of file, which is not an expected behavior.

> When you want to download multiple files at once, you have to **zip**
>   the files and download.

check this link: [download multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886141/download-multiple-files-java-spring)