# Download multiple file from spring boot service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to send multiple files to UI from db,
I saw couple of post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886141/download-multiple-files-java-spring) and [here](https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-download), it suggest that I need to zip multiple files and send to client, but my client is front end angular code which unable to handle zip file.
I

tried code like below

```
public ResponseEntity<List<ByteArrayResouse>> downloaFile(){
 List<ByteArrayResource> listOfFiles = fileServices.getFiles();
return ResponseEntity.ok()
       .contentType(MdiaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
       .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=somefile")
       .body(listOfFiles);
}
```

but I got error saying 406 could not find acceptable representation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download Multiple files Java Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886141/download-multiple-files-java-spring)

Comment: but all are returning null or void, but I want to pass that to my UI, how would I do that?