how to return multiple byte[] in springboot controller
for getAllInvoices i need the method in controllerclass.


    public List<byte[]> getAllInvoices() {
        Iterable<Invoice> invoices = repos.findAll();
        List<byte[]> invoicesData = new ArrayList<>();
    
        for (Invoice invoice : invoices) {
            byte[] invoiceData = ImageUtil.decompressImage(invoice.getInvoiceData());
            invoicesData.add(invoiceData);
        }
        return invoicesData;
    }


@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<byte[]>> getAllInvoices() {
        List<byte[]> invoicesPdfBytes = service.getAllInvoices();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("inline", "invoice.pdf");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(invoicesPdfBytes);
    }
 

this propably dont work because now all the invoices returned in one file invoice.pdf?
is this possible at all?
@Alex & @AndrewL  thanks for tips,
Yess i'm working on the zipmethod, and the response has to give a view-only -contentDisposition"inline"- because the user download the invoices in method GET ("/download/{order_id}") downloadInvoiceByOrderId -contentDisposition"attachment"-  piece by piece allready...
this method getAllInvoices/getInvoicesByCustomer() has to show the pdf's.
I tried to define the zipfile but it stil doesn't work well, i get raw code (??ff/bel??ffx????m??/fmx?bel??  etc.) in response in postman.
my code:
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllInvoices() throws IOException {

        List<byte[]> invoicesData = service.getAllInvoices();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

        for (int i = 0; i < invoicesData.size(); i++) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("invoice-insight" + (i + 1) + ".pdf");
            zipEntry.setSize(invoicesData.get(i).length);
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zipOutputStream.write(invoicesData.get(i));
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        }

        zipOutputStream.close();
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("inline", "invoices.zip");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


You can wrap all invoices in one zip file and return it. Or you can try to follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131993/12199915

Does this answer your question? Download multiple files with a single action

I don't follow the revised text in the Question: (1) you seem to say the user has made multiple REST calls. How is this relevant? (2) Your getAllInvoices() looks ok (3) Postman is trying to display the binary data in is view window - you cannot "display" a zip file like this.  I suggest you use either (a) a browser to download the zip file or (b) a tool liek wget etc to obtain the file, then unzip locally and test.  If your user won't understand how to handle a zip file, then like my answer below says you'll need a different approach.

So it's not possible to give more byte[] pdf's back to client in a single request right? in the browser the downloads run and work well so it's ok!
Is it usual in production that a GET-request for multiple invoices/pdf's (just view not necessarily download) is handled in the frontend by give multiple getRequests to backend end collect them to give back to client in one response or something like that?

It is not possible to return multiple files from a single HTTP call, (regardless of the server language)
You could,

as @Alex suggests wrap the files in a container like Zip
provide multiple links for the caller to download one at a time.
(you might be able to induce a JavaScript application to write multiple files, but if this was possible in the past, it may very well be prohibited now, to safeguard the browser user from attack by a rogue server.)

See Download multiple files with a single action

I edited my question, you see whats wrong?
