# Spring Request Mapping post vs put, same method, same logic, but

Tags: spring, rest, post, spring-boot, put

I have a 2 method:
first one create product:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Validated ProductDTO productDTO){
        productService.addProduct(productDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Maxsulot ro'yhatga qo'shildi", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

another one update product:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@Validated ProductDTO productDTO){
        productService.update(productDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Maxsulot ma'lumotlari yangilandi", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Now, I am surprized that, if I sent same data post method works fine(screen1), but put(screen2) method return validation error. 
screen1(post)
[image]

screen2(put)
[image]

What the problem is?
MyDTO class:

```
public class ProductDTO {

    private Long id;

    private MultipartFile file;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50)
    private String productName;

    @NotNull
    private Long productPrice;

    private String productInfo;

    @NotNull
    private Long categoryId;

    private String unitOfMeasurement;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: what is the magic, guy ? :)

Comment: can you post what does your application writes to the console? You can see that there is some BindException and from this message you might be able to determine where it comes from.

Comment: can you share the code of you DTO object? Do you have any initBinders?

Comment: I had added Mydto class

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If not make sure to add the `HttpPutFormContentFilter` to your list of filters.

Comment: Yeah, i am using spring boot

Comment: Which version? Do you have configured web mvc yourself or relying on Spring Boot? Add some configuration

Comment: I have not used custom configuration, all configs are default

Comment: Which configuration should I add ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have `@Validated` that should validate your request body according to `JSR-303`.

Seems like it is not consistent when you `POST` and `PUT`. It validates/not validating and return an error because your body does not match the validation rules you placed on `ProductDTO`.

In all the docs I saw you should do something like `@Valid @RequestBody` instead of just putting `@Validated`.

Try to change it to the above and see if it now work more consistently.

Comment: If I change `@Validated` to `@Valid @RequestBody`, server couldn't parse Multipart file. This error appers: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`

Comment: Wow, Put method returns Error#415, Unsupported MediaType :-)

Comment: This is a different problem, look on this posts: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081079/rest-http-post-multipart-with-json) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344455/unable-to-send-a-multipart-mixed-request-to-spring-mvc-based-rest-service)