# no multipart boundary was found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httprequest

Using Rest Client Chrome tool, I am uploading a JSON file say sample.json in my request. Getting below exception. 
Tried Passing header as multipart/form-data and also no passing the latter. But the result is same. Am I doing right?

```
the request 
was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

..

```
public HttpEntity<?> uploadJsonFile(@PathVariable("jsonFileID") String
    jsonFileID, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception 
    {
        // Some code here
    }
```

..

```
Failed to parse multipart 
servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: 
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request 
was rejected because no multipart boundary was found] with root cause

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request 
was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2884) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3232) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not specifying a boundary in your HTTP request header - see here for what I mean [Unable to send a multipart/mixed request to spring MVC based REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344455/unable-to-send-a-multipart-mixed-request-to-spring-mvc-based-rest-service)

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=YourBoundaryOfChoiceHere
```

Comment: What is that boundary mean?

Comment: Content-Type: multipart means essentially just that - a message split into multiple parts and sent as such. The boundary is a separator between those parts. if your boundary was "abc", the separator would be "--abc--" as defined in HTTP standards

Answer (score 3):

For your eyes only, in java you might use :

```
String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());
            request.getHeaders().setContentType("multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' from header

Worked for me